# Angular material is not working in my project and there is nor error

Tags: angular, angular-material

this is my login form and its not rendering in browser and also there is no elements in dom.

```
  <mat-card>
    <form [FormGroup]="loginForm">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input type="email" formControlName="email" matInput placeholder="Email">
      </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input type="password" formControlName="password" matInput placeholder="Password">
    </mat-form-field>
    </form>
 </mat-card>
```

Comment: Did you import the appropriate modules? https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api and https://material.angular.io/components/card/api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing all `Angular` material modules in your application for the sake of all information at one place.

So, create `ngmat.module.ts` file in your, for example, `project/src/app/share` directory and paste the following code.

> **Note:** It is good to maintain a separate module. However just import only the required one's and others may be kept commented.

It would be fine if your application is module based, for example, if you have user module then you can share the `NgMatModule` in your `user.module.ts` file like this:

```
import { NgMatModule } from '../share/ngmat.module';
```

**ngmat.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';    

@NgModule( {
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,

        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatBadgeModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatPaginatorModule    
    ],
    exports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatBadgeModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatPaginatorModule
    ],
    providers: [
        MatDatepickerModule,
    ]
} )

export class NgMatModule { }
```